# Не работает label в браузере на samsung

Tags: android, css, label, samsung

В браузере телефона samsung не работает label. Сделал меню через тег label, кнопка бутеброд через label, нажимаю в телефоне на неё - она не работает. Как прописать префиксы или что можно сделать?

Спасибо!

Comment: Код свой покажите

Comment: http://alexeyfry.beget.tech/index.html - вот ссылка на сайт. Там ещё на Samsung Internet Browser не работает слайдер. Я его делал через label и <input type="radio">. Ссылки меню и кнопку бургер через чекбоксы и label тоже. Везде всё нормально работает, кроме на Samsung Internet Browser. Может там просто CSS такой не поддерживает?